# Flutter: How to use DropDown Button to sorting Data

Tags: flutter

I have a JSON file like this ([API](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tft-test-48c87.appspot.com/o/sort.json?alt=media&token=a9c26c11-90e5-4c1c-9c72-201541a42593))

```
[
  {
    "language": "English",
    "bySpeakers": 1121,
    "inCountry": 59,
    "onInternet": 0.04
  },
  {
    "language": "French",
    "bySpeakers": 284.9,
    "inCountry": 29,
    "onInternet": 0.02
  },
  {
    "language": "Spanish",
    "bySpeakers": 512.9,
    "inCountry": 21,
    "onInternet": 0.01
  },
  {
    "language": "Arabic",
    "bySpeakers": 422,
    "inCountry": 26,
    "onInternet": 0.053
  },
  {
    "language": "Portuguse",
    "bySpeakers": 236.5,
    "inCountry": 9,
    "onInternet": 0.01
  }
]
```

I want that when I click on the `DropdownButton` then select each button => the list will be sorted as follows:

- **Default** => default of list
- **Alphabet** => sort list in alphabetical order
- **By Speakers** => sort list in double `bySpeakers` order
  (descending)
- **In Countries** => sort list in int `inCountry` order
  (descending)
- **On Internet** => sort list in double `onInternet` order
  (descending)

[image]

So pls help me, this is the main file:

```
import 'package:ask/model/sort_model.dart';
import 'package:ask/services/sort_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SortPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SortPageState createState() => _SortPageState();
}

class _SortPageState extends State<SortPage> {
  List<Sort> _sort = [];
  List<String> dropDown = <String>["Default", "Alphabet", "By Speakers", "In Countries", "On Internet"];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SortServices.getData().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        _sort = data;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text('Sort'),
            new DropdownButton<String>(
                underline: Container(),
                icon: Icon(Icons.sort,color: Colors.white),
                items: dropDown.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  setState(() {});
                })
          ],
        )),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [Text('Language'), Text('By Speakers'), Text('In Countries'), Text('On Internet')],
              ),
            ),
            for (Sort s in _sort)
              Row(children: [
                Expanded(child: Text(s.language)),
                Expanded(child: Text('${s.bySpeakers} billion')),
                Expanded(child: Text('${s.inCountry} countries')),
                Expanded(child: Text('${s.onInternet * 100} %')),
              ])
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dart, the `List` type has a `sort` function which lets you sort the list. You give the `sort` function another function that compares between any two objects in the list. It returns an integer that represents whether an object is less than, equal to or larger than the other object. If the returned value is `-1` (might work for all negative numbers but I'm not sure), this means that the first object is less that the second object. If it's `0`, they're equal, and if it's `1` (again, might work for all positives but not sure) the first object is larger than the second.

I assume your `Sort` class is defined as follows:

```dart
class Sort{
  String language;
  double bySpeakers, inCountries, onInternet;
}
```

To sort the list `_sort` alphabetically, your sort call will look something like this:

```dart
_sort.sort((first, second) => first.language.compareTo(second.language));
```

Note that this function call will change the list itself. If you want to keep your original list, make sure you're sorting a copy of the list. A soft copy (only copy references to a new array) can be achieved using `map` like this:

```dart
List<Sort> copy = _sort.map((e) => e).toList();
```

I'll give one more sort example for the `bySpeakers` field:

```dart
// Sort the list using the bySpeakers attribute
_sort.sort((first, second){
  if(first.bySpeakers > second.bySpeakers)
    return 1;
  else if(first.bySpeakers < second.bySpeakers)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;
});
```

Note that `sort` sorts in ascending order. To make it descending, you can swap between `return 1;` and `return -1;`, or use the getter `reversed` on the list, which will return an `Iterable` containing the reversed list.

So define a function that does the sorting:

```dart
// function defined in the state class
void sortItems(String value){
  // assuming the original list is stored _originalList
  _sort = _originalList.map((e)=>e).toList();
  switch(value){
    case 'Alphabet':
      _sort.sort((first, second)=>first.language.comprateTo(second.language));
      break;
    case 'By Speakers':
      _sort.sort((first, second){
        if(first.bySpeakers > second.bySpeakers)
          return -1; // reversed
        else if(first.bySpeakers < second.bySpeakers)
          return 1; // reversed
        else
          return 0;
      });
      break;
    
    case 'In Countries':
      _sort.sort((first, second){
        if(first.inCountries > second.inCountries)
          return -1; // reversed
        else if(first.inCountries < second.inCountries)
          return 1; // reversed
        else
          return 0;
      });
      break;
    
    case 'On Internet':
      _sort.sort((first, second){
        if(first.onInternet > second.onInternet)
          return -1; // reversed
        else if(first.onInternet < second.onInternet)
          return 1; // reversed
        else
          return 0;
      });
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Now you will need to call this function inside the `onChanged` function for the `DropdownButton`, something like this:

```dart
onChanged: (String value) {
  setState(() {
    sortItems(value);
  });
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the very detailed and helpful answer, it works except `_originalList`, I have no idea [where to put it](https://imgur.com/t1Cojdo), please check it for me

Comment: Define another list in your state, then in `initState`, when you get the data from the service, store `data` in both lists

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:ask/model/sort_model.dart';
import 'package:ask/services/sort_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SortPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SortPageState createState() => _SortPageState();
}

class _SortPageState extends State<SortPage> {
  List<Sort> _sort = [];
  List<String> dropDown = <String>["Default", "Alphabet", "By Speakers", "In Countries", "On Internet"];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SortServices.getData().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        _sort = data;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text('Sort'),
            new DropdownButton<String>(
                underline: Container(),
                icon: Icon(Icons.sort,color: Colors.white),
                items: dropDown.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList()..sort((a, b) => b.value!.compareTo(a.value!)),
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  setState(() {});
                })
          ],
        )),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [Text('Language'), Text('By Speakers'), Text('In Countries'), Text('On Internet')],
              ),
            ),
            for (Sort s in _sort)
              Row(children: [
                Expanded(child: Text(s.language)),
                Expanded(child: Text('${s.bySpeakers} billion')),
                Expanded(child: Text('${s.inCountry} countries')),
                Expanded(child: Text('${s.onInternet * 100} %')),
              ])
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).